# Spring sending object from view to a controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, view, thymeleaf

How can I send an object from a View to a Controller?
I'm first using a Controller 1 to display this object on a View 1 using Thymeleaf, the object is `${object}`. Then what I want to do is to click a button and send this object back to a Controller 2 so that I can display that same object from View 1 to View 2. How do you do that, can you give me an example please?

Right now I can do that using the ID of the object in the URL and then requesting the parameter in Controller 2, then getting the object based on the ID. But I don't want to see the object ID in the URL, what is another method?

Comment: https://www.javaguides.net/2019/04/spring-boot-thymeleaf-crud-example-tutorial.html

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help me, I said I can already work with the ID of the object in the URL then etracting it using the @PathVariableWhat I'm asking is how can I transport an object of a view to a controller without seeing the ID or anything from the object in the URL?

Comment: Doesnt look like it that you have any option. You must get the object based on something. At least one identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an id in the URL, then you can create a form with a hidden field and submit that to your controller.

```
<form th:object="${formData}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

With the controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping
  public String showPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("formData", new MyFormData("someId"));

    return "myTemplate";
  }

  @PostMapping
  public String handleId(@ModelAttribute("formData") MyFormData formData) {
    String id = formData.getId();
    
    // do something with id here
  }
}
```

But it seems you make it a bit hard with this requirement. Any particular reason you don't want to show the id in the URL?

Comment: I wanted to stop other users from editing another user's objects for example I have a form that adds books to a user /addBook/{user_id} And I didnt want another user to acess the URL with another user's id to add books for him. there's a better practice?

Comment: This approach is no substitute for security. When using "View source" in the browser, they can see the value of the hidden input. You need to add security to your application (usually via Spring Security for a Spring Boot application) and retrieve the logged on user via `@AuthenticationPrincipal` for example. Do not rely on the user id in the URL or the hidden input to know what user is currently logged on.